# SQL PHP Pull down menu with related records radio buttons delete

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a foto system and have no problems deleting albums from SQL and uploading albums.
What I do have a big problem with is when I try to get a list dropdownmenu with all the albums, I can not figure out how to delete a picture from that particular album. I can get the whole list of pictures from MySQL but as soon as I implement the pulldown menu I'm not able to delete, it must be something really simple but it's driving me nuts.

This is the album code which works fine

```
<!--Album Block-->
<div id='album' class='album box desc admin_title'>
<div class='admin_block_left'>
<h3 class='admin_blocks'><?php echo $lang['ADMIN_ALBUM_HEADER'];?></h3>
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<div class='admin_labels'><label for='album_title'><?php echo    $lang['ALBUM_TITLE_BOX'];?></label></div>
<div class='admin_labels'><input type='text' name='album_title'   id='album_title' size='64'></div>
<div class='admin_labels'><label for='album_photo'><?php echo   $lang['ALBUM_PHOTO_BOX'];?></label></div>
<div class='admin_labels'><input type='file' name='album_photo' id='album_photo'></div>
<div class='admin_labels'><input type='submit'  onchange=\'reload(this.form)\' value='<?php echo  $lang['ALBUM_UPLOAD_BUTTON'];?>'></div>
</form>
<h3 class='admin_blocks'><?php echo $lang['ADMIN_PREVIEW'];?></h3>
<div class='album_preview_block'>
</div>
</div>
<div class='admin_block_right'>
<h3 class='admin_blocks'><?php echo $lang['ADMIN_ALBUM_LIST'];?></h3>
<div class='album_list'>
<form method="post">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT album_id, album_title FROM {$album_table} ORDER BY album_id DESC");
{
while(list($album_id, $album_title) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
echo "<li><input type='radio' name='del_album' checked='true'   value='{$album_id}' onchange=\'reload(this.form)\'> {$album_title} &ndash;   {$album_id} </ul>";
 }
 ?>
</div>
<?php echo $album_title;?>
<div class='admin_delete_button'>
<input type='submit' onchange=\'reload(this.form)\' value='<?php echo   $lang['ADMIN_DELETE_ALBUM'];?>'>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

this is what I just can't get to work :

```
<?php include_once 'database.php';?>
<?php
echo "<form method=post>";
echo "<select name='album' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option    value=''>Select one First</option>";
 foreach ($dbo->query($quer2) as $noticia2)
{
if($noticia2['album_id']==@$album){echo "<option selected    value='$noticia2[album_id]'>$noticia2[album_title]</option>"."<BR>";}
else{echo  "<option value='$noticia2[album_id]'>$noticia2[album_title]   </option>";}
 }
 echo "</select>";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT picture_id, picture_title, image_time FROM   {$picture_table} ORDER BY id DESC");
echo '<div id="album_block_right">
<div id="album_list"><ul name="album">';
foreach ($dbo->query($quer) as $noticia)
{
echo  "<li><input type='radio' name='del_picture' value='{$picture_id}'>   $noticia[picture_title] $noticia[image_time]</li>";
}
echo "</ul><input type=submit onchange=\'reload(this.form)\' value='Delete Picture' name=del_picture></div>";
 echo "</form>";
 ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you mixing MySQL methodologies? It looks like you're using `mysql_` functions alongside `mysqli_`. If that is what you're doing none of this will work.

Comment: It does display the pulldown menu, and gives me a list with with radio buttons. to be honest I dont know the diffrence between mysql _ and mysqli_ I think I'm just using mysql_ the code that is faulty was copied of the internet and to be honest I would like to get rid of it. All I want is a pull down menu from one table, displaying the related results from the second table with radio buttons, and a delete button to delete the related record